# Problema al pasar un dato long a un service en Android

Tags: java, android

Intento pasar una variable de tipo `long` a un servicio el cual es el tiempo en el que se va ejecutar pero me marca el siguiente error

```
9-27 00:33:16.364 14153-15553/com.android.controlmovil E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[enviar_coord_background]
  Process: com.android.controlmovil, PID: 14153
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
      at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
      at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345)
      at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:321)
      at com.android.controlmovil.enviar_coord_background.onHandleIntent(enviar_coord_background.java:70)
      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Mi código es

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(enrolar_ws.this, enviar_coord_background.class);
intent1.putExtra("rango",rango_spinner);                                    
startService(intent1);
```

Y en mi service es

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        boolean band=false;
        long rango;

        try {
           rango = Long.parseLong(intent.getStringExtra("rango"));

            while(band==true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rango);
                    comenzarLocalizacion(enviar_coord_background.this);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //}
    }
```

Comment: tendrias que contralar el valor null del objeto antes de la llamada o bien en el servicio y devolver o una excepción controlada o bien un mesanje informativo del error.

Comment: sólo añade (long) al número, por default todo número entero es int, agregando un long estás casteando tu entero

Comment: crea una variable long e inicializala con cero, si el parseo es exitoso le fijas el!nuevo valor si no envias la variable inicializada en cero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema especificado en tu LogCat es :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"

Ya que dentro de tu método `onHandleIntent()` trata de realizar un parseo para convertir un valor a long, pero este valor es null.

```
rango = Long.parseLong(intent.getStringExtra("rango"));
```

Rapidamente podrias realizar una validación para evitar este problema:

```
if(intent.getStringExtra("rango")!= null){
rango = Long.parseLong(intent.getStringExtra("rango"));
}else{
rango = 0;
}
```

Pero es importante revisar porque el valor que envias es null desde el intent, podrías realizar una validación mediante una operación ternaria:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(enrolar_ws.this, enviar_coord_background.class);
intent1.putExtra("rango", rango_spinner!=null? rango_spinner:0 );                                    
startService(intent1);
```

Comment: no entiendo el -1..me parece buena la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Elena me has ayudado de nuevo ;D

Comment: Excelente Carlos! =)

Comment: No tengo mucho conocimiento en Android, pero creo que se incluyen las librerías de Apache Commons Lang 2. De ser así, esto se puede reducir dramáticamente a [NumberUtils#toLong(intent.getStringExtra("rango"));](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#toLong(java.lang.String))

Comment: Muy cierto! Hay varias clases de mucha utilidad en la librería Apache Commons Lang!, pero se tiene que agrerar el .jar o actualmente definir la dependencia para utilizarlas. El sdk esta evolucionando y tal vez en un futuro no muy lejano se tenga algo similar. Por ejemplo hay clases como las de conectividad de Apache que ya se marcaron como obsoletas en Android: org.apache.http

Comment: Por cierto, aunque se tendría que agregar la dependencia,  lo que comentas puede ser otra respuesta para solucionar esta pregunta! :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando le pones al intent el `long` extra `rango_spinner`, su valor es `null`.

```
// rango_spinner = null
intent1.putExtra("rango",rango_spinner);
```

Deberías hacer un check, comprobar si el valor es `null` para no iniciar el servicio y mostrar un mensaje al usuario.

Por ejemplo:

```
if (rango_spinner != null) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(enrolar_ws.this, enviar_coord_background.class);
    intent1.putExtra("rango",rango_spinner);                                    
    startService(intent1);  
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Debes introducir un rango",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
```

---

Hasta aquí el primer problema, pero...

- ¿Porque si enviamos valor `null` hay una `NumberFormatException` en vez de una `NullPointerException`?

Lo que pasa después es que recuperas el extra como un `String`, ya que usas `intent.getStringExtra("rango")`, por lo que no recuperas `null` como `long`, sino como `String`, por lo que intentas parsear la cadena `"null"` con lo que se provoca la:

> `NumberFormatException`: Invalid long: `"null"`

Para evitar esto, inserta de este modo:

```
intent1.putExtra("rango", (long) rango_spinner);
```

<sup>*he hecho un casting sencillo, pero quizás debes convertirlo con `Long.valueOf` o similar*.</sup>

Y recuperar el extra con [`Intent::getLongExtra(java.lang.String, long`)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getLongExtra(java.lang.String,%20long)), con lo que además, tendrás un valor por defecto en el caso que no quieras realizar el primer check propuesto y puedas recibir datos erróneos.

```
try {
    rango = intent.getLongExtra("rango", 2L));

    while(band==true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rango);
            comenzarLocalizacion(enviar_coord_background.this);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}catch (NullPointerException e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

[EXTRA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913263/6751395): por si quieres saber que esta pasando, aquí tienes la implementación de `getLongExtra`:

```
public long getLongExtra(String name, long defaultValue) {
   return mExtras == null ? defaultValue : mExtras.getLong(name, defaultValue);
}
```